# Warning: Undefined array key "margin_widescreen"

Tags: wordpress, responsive, elementor

Im using elementor in wordpress and Im facing these errors:

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_widescreen" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776

```
    Warning: Undefined array key "margin_laptop" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "margin_tablet" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "margin_mobile" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "padding_widescreen" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "padding_laptop" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "padding_tablet" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776
    
    Warning: Undefined array key "padding_mobile" in C:\xampp\htdocs\innstylesalon\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 776`
```

the error will be gone after the first reload, meaning that I wont be able to see it once I refresh the page or enter the page for the second time

Im using `PHP Version 8.2.4` `with wordpress version 6.3`

I tried increasing the memory size for WordPress in the custom codes section of `wp_config.php`
`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');` 
still did not work

I tried deactivating all my plugins and activating them one by one and when I leave `elementorKit lite` deactivated, the error wouldn't appear.
but I need that plugin, and I was not facing this earlier; so there must be another way.

Comment: I noticed these PHP warnings as well. Still i think the proper way would be to ask for support at Elementor's wordpress.org support page for the free version. Premium users should ask for support at elementor.kustomer.help .

Comment: If you haven't written any code about this on your own, you should report this as a bug to the maintainers of the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling one page scroll in elementkits settings, fixed the job for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `onepage scroll` and don’t want to disable then you can fix that error by replacing `get_page_setting` method at `wp-content/plugins/elementskit-lite/modules/onepage-scroll/init.php` with below method.

```
public static function get_page_setting( $id ) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $page_settings_manager = \Elementor\Core\Settings\Manager::get_settings_managers( 'page' );
    $page_settings   = $page_settings_manager->get_model( $post_id )->get_data('settings');
    return isset($page_settings[$id]) ? $page_settings[$id] : false;
}
```

Otherwise you can disable `onepage scroll`

We hope the ElementsKit team will release a fix soon.

Answer (score -1):

In file public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/files/css/base.php
Just add the below

if ( ! isset( $values[ $control['name'] ] ) ) { return null; }

Before line 778 ($value = $values[ $control['name'] ];)

it will fix it.

Comment: Editing plugin files is never a good ideas, as this "fix" would get removed on updating the plugin. Also, how is that array key `name` related to the array key `margin-widescreen` from the error message?