# Warning: Undefined array key "margin_laptop" in

Tags: wordpress, responsive, elementor

Im using elementor in wordpress and Im facing these errors:

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_laptop" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

```
Warning: Undefined array key "margin_laptop" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_tablet_extra" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_tablet" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_mobile_extra" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "margin_mobile" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "padding_laptop" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "padding_tablet_extra" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "padding_tablet" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "padding_mobile_extra" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778

Warning: Undefined array key "padding_mobile" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ladiescollege\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\files\css\base.php on line 778
```

I tried disabling all the plugins and activating them one by one but cannot identify this error.

Comment: Did you try delete old elementor plugin and install new?

Comment: If you disable the plugin and the problem persists. Check if the theme is updated. Similarly, ensure Elementor plugin is updated as well. If they are up-to-date, consider temporarily changing the theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Undefined array key "margin\_widescreen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76897575/warning-undefined-array-key-margin-widescreen)